# nullsoft installer to install silverlight

Tags: silverlight, nsis

Does anyone know if silverlight can be packaged into an installer such as NSIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSIS can easily fire off other msi or install exes and wait for them to finish. So yes. And if Silverlight has a silent switch for executing the install then the process will look seamless.

Comment: nice, i didnt see that silverlight came down as an exe. I havnt installed it for so long.

Comment: You should examine the return code after the msi process completes to insure it installed successfully.  Prior to kicking it off silently, you should also display a message telling the user to please wait, as it may appear to the user that your installer has frozen while it waits for the MSI to complete.  I use Banner plugin for this: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Banner/Readme.txt 
  Alternatively there are often msi command line options that let you run the MSI such that it is completely automated(no user input), but it will still display the msi install window with progress bars.